# HTML5 drawimage from video to canvas

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-canvas

I was trying to capture a frame from video and drawing it in canvas using HTML5, but the below code is not working. when i click on the start button the canvas is filled with black color

```
    <video src="video2.mp4" autoplay="true" type="video/mp4" width="300" height="200" id="vid">
        </video>
        <canvas id="cvs"> </canvas>
        <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
        <script>
        var video=document.getElementById("vid");
        var cvs=document.getElementById("cvs");
        function start(){
        cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, 300,200);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, and I think it had to with the video format. My video was H264 in an .mp4 container. When I used an .ogg video, the exact same code worked perfectly.
I'm using the code from the link that was provided by Romin.